# Updating an item using LINQ, not working

Tags: linq

Good day!

I have this query as shown below:

```
jt.SummarySpecs.Where(
x => true
)
.FirstOrDefault()
.DocSpecs
.Where(
    x => x.DocID == x.DocID
)
.FirstOrDefault()
.FinishingOptionsDesc[0] = option;
```

But when the code get executed, value for finishingOptionsDesc[0] is not updating...

what's wrong with the query above?

---

The classes attributes:

```
"SummarySpecs.cs"
    public DocSpec[] DocSpecs { get; set; }

"DocSpecs.cs"
    public string[] FinishingOptionsDesc { get; set; }
```

---

My only concern is to update the FinishingOptionDesc 1st string.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do in where clause, "x.DocSpecs == x.DocSpecs", cause both are same...

Comment: I intended to have it that way so that I can check the data under "DocSpecs" object.  Sorry I am still new in LINQ...

Comment: see, instead of giving the same value in both side, give some static value like 1, 2 and see if its updating or not....Where(x=> x.DocID == 1)

Comment: .Where( x => true ), tried this one instead but value is not updating.

Comment: Can you update your question and show me the data in your tables SummarySpecs and DocSpecs.

Answer (score 1):

That error means something is null. You have 4 unchecked places in one statement where there could be a null return value. Either of the calls to FirstOrDefault could return null if those collections were empty. Or DocSpecs could be null on the returned object, or FinishingOptionsDesc could be null.

Ideally you'd break this statement up a bit and insert null checks. You could say that you know none of these points should *ever* be null. If that is the case it may be valid to allow an exception to occur, but arguably it is still worth breaking up the statement to get better error reporting on where the exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..
**UPDATE**

```
if(jt.SummarySpecs.Select(a=>a.DocSpecs).Any())
{
    var docSpecs = jt.SummarySpecs.Select(a => a.DocSpecs)
    docSpecs.FinishingOptionsDesc[0] = option;
}
```

Comment: it wont work.  if(jt.SummarySpecs.DocSpecs.Any()).  after "SummarySpecs," there's no option for DocSpecs.  possible options are "where, select, any and so on...."

Comment: do you have any DocSpecs?, if not create few DocSpecs and SummarySpecs and then try...